# How to perform Binary Classification with many features using ML.Net

Tags: c#, sentiment-analysis, multiclass-classification, ml.net

So I’ve been messing with ML.net and practicing using their examples and was wondering how I would train a model with the following input:

int, string, int, string, int, string, int, string, bool (Label)

and predict the binary label provided the other 8 features.

The first 3 strings are selections that could be converted to a lookup, and the fourth string is random text that needs more of a sentiment approach.

Any ideas on where to start / how to approach this? I’ve implemented using multiclass classification but I don’t think it makes sense since my output is binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [this sample](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/BinaryClassification_HeartDiseaseDetection) from the ML.NET sample Github.

You can use any of these [Binary Classifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.binaryclassificationcatalog.binaryclassificationtrainers?view=ml-dotnet) for the lookups checkout the [MapValueToKey Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.conversionsextensionscatalog.mapvaluetokey?view=ml-dotnet), and for the additional fourth string you'll need to work with the [Text Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.text?view=ml-dotnet), but there's nothing pretrained.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This helped a ton, thanks! I guess my biggest issue was understanding the pipeline. I've since recreated the app a bunch of times with different setups and now understand a lot more about how the process works.